# Laravel adding to poviders array inside config/app programical

Tags: laravel

after installing some packages in `laravel` we should add class definition to `providers` array. as you know we have this array:

```php
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
    App\Providers\AnnotationsServiceProvider::class,
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
],
```

my question is how can i add class to this array programical? does any ability in laravel to add it? for example:

```php
App::install();
```

Comment: Laravel 5.5+ has [automatic package discovery](https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/package-auto-discovery-in-laravel-5-5-ea9e3ab20518), meaning you don't need to add anything in the providers array. And you shouldn't change `app.php` in your code since it should be in your VCS and gets cached by the framework.

Comment: @Remul you suppose after installing `nwdart` we should add it to providers

Comment: No, for most packages you don't have to add anything to the providers array when installing it.

Comment: @Remul ok. now how can i add for some packages which should be added into this array?

Comment: You do it manually in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a later or equal version of Laravel 5.5, you can use your package's `composer.json` file to register your classes automatically by using Laravel's package discovery feature:

```json
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "providers": [
            "Foo\\Bar\\ServiceProvider"
        ],
        "aliases": {
            "Bar": "Foo\\Bar\\Facade"
        }
    }
}
```

to add providers and aliases into the application's runtime configuration. Many packages support it now without doing anything.